# Find a Directory/Folder with CMD without knowing full path

Tags: command-line

I don't know the full path to a folder, just the folder name. I would like to find everywhere where this folder is using CMD. Is there a command that does this?

I am looking for an equivalent to *nix's:

```
find . -name <folder name> -type d
```

Is there anything like that in Windows CMD? I know dir /s ...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So at the root of the drive:

```
dir <Folder Name> /AD /s
```

Comment: /A- Displays files with specified attributes. D-May the attribute be Directories /s - Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this search to hidden subfolders as well?

Comment: It is searching only in  C drive

Comment: Then tell it to search in whichever drive you want.

Comment: To get a compact listing of all directory location, you can add /B, like this: `dir <Folder Name> /AD/S/B`

Answer (score 14):

1. switch to the root-search-folder (e.g. C:)
2. type `dir /S /P <file or foldername>` (/P pauses after each screenful of information)

If you'd like a list of all occurances of a specific filename, you can simply redirect the output to a file:

```
dir /S <filename> > c:\results.txt
```

You can also narrow down your results by using the /A switch of the dir command.
If you'd like to only list directories, you can append `/AD` to your command:

```
dir /S /P <filename> /AD
```

Other possibilities are:

```
 /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
 attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
              H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
              S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
              L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
```

If you'd like to know more about the dir command, just type `dir /?`into your cmd.

Comment: np, maybe worth an upvote? ;)

Comment: Definitely worth it, but my rep isn't high enough on this sub-SOF hahaha

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /S /b
```

/S searches recursively

/b removes the additional directory metadata from the search results, so you get a nice clean list of files

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. See https://i.imgur.com/X0MCR1p.png

Comment: @DavidPostill - yes it does, your pictyure shows you asking for the contents of 'test', which contains the single item 'test' (at least that's all we can see in it), and the /b flag removes the heading metadata. Without the /b flag, the root directory is also shown

Comment: My point stands. Using `\b` **omits** `f:\test` from the listing. It returns one file when there are two. Therefore the answer is wrong.