# Find all directories containing semicolon ( ; )

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I search for all directories/folders which contain the character `;`.

From [**this question**](https://superuser.com/q/428088) I see I can search for any other character using, e.g. to find all directories containing `a`

```
dir /S *a* /AD
```

However, `;` acts as a delimiter, so doing `*;*` is telling it to find `*` or `*`, i.e. *Anything* or *anything*, and returning every subdirectory rather than just those containing `;`.

This would be great if I wanted to find, e.g. `x` or `y` as I could `*x*;*y*`, but how do I match `;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should quote the pattern:

```
dir /s /ad "*;*"
```

This way DIR will treat `*;*` as a single token. This is also useful for other special characters, like space, comma, caret (`^`), etc.